# Custom php Widget keeps disappearing from the front end

Tags: widgets, cache

I've created a widget to show custom testimonials on the sidebar.

It checks if the post has a custom field 'customer_review' then prints a it on the sidebar.

Thing is, the testimonial keeps disappearing. I think it might have something to do with the flush_widget_cache function. I got this code from a tutorial, can't find it now.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "eb_testimonial_widget" );' ) );

class eb_testimonial_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'eb_testimonial_widget', 'description' => __( "") );
        parent::__construct('eb_testimonial_widget', __('ExcelB Testimonials Widget'), $widget_ops);
        $this->alt_option_name = 'eb_testimonial_widget';

        add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
        add_action( 'deleted_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        $cache = wp_cache_get('eb_testimonial_widget', 'widget');

        if ( !is_array($cache) )
            $cache = array();

        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) )
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;

        if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) ) {
            echo $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ];
            return;
        }

        ob_start();
        extract($args);

        $title = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Testimonial' );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );



        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        $review = get_post_meta($post_id, 'customer_review', true);

        if( $review )  :

            echo $before_widget;
            if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
            ?>

            <div class="my_textwidget">
                <?php
                    ?>
                    <div class="customer-review">
                        <p><?php echo $review; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php echo $after_widget;

        endif;  


        $cache[$args['widget_id']] = ob_get_flush();
        wp_cache_set('eb_testimonial_widget', $cache, 'widget');
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        if ( isset($alloptions['eb_testimonial_widget']) )
            delete_option('eb_testimonial_widget');

        return $instance;
    }

    function flush_widget_cache() {
        wp_cache_delete('eb_testimonial_widget', 'widget');
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : 'Testimonial';
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you suspect `flush_widget_cache` to be a problem, have commented out the lines that run that function to see what happens?

Comment: @s_ha_dum sorry for the late reply. Yes indeed I tried and the same thing kept happening.
I've now solved it by removing everything cache related. However I dont believe thats a good thing

Comment: Well, you've narrowed it down to this: "The caching logic is wrong". Yes, you should be caching as much as possible but something with the implementation is causing trouble. I don't have time to try to sort that out, but I will try to watch the thread and will answer if I spot something.

Comment: Dont worry man, thanks for commenting. The cache is acting really weird. As you can see in the code I get the post/page ID. The ID was actually being cached throughout the pages.
So suddenly it would get cached in a page that didn't have a custom field 'review', and other times with one that did. And thats why it kept appearing/disappearing randomly.

Comment: Are there caching plugins involved, or does the server itself do any caching?

Comment: w3 total cache.

Comment: With w3 total cache disabled does the code perform more as expected?

Comment: Thing is, this is a client's client's website (if that makes sense) and I cannot disable anything.
I should look more deeply into this with a localhost install. However I'm going to leave it as is for now.
In case someone finds this, just remember removing cache related lines works but it's not the best solution.
Those lines were probably wrongly setup in the first place